# activeadmin: how do I controle what header menu items show based on user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I would like to create some logic with in my Rails app that is using ActiveAdmin backend and I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

Basically I'm wanting to give each AdminUser a new property called client_id. When the user logs in I would like to filter what is shown to them in the header menu.

Each item in the header will all have a "client_id" so that I can filter them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but you'll be doing a bit of custom stuff to get that working.

I'd suggest you would be way better off just rolling your own admin setup.  You're going to jump through hoops and do some hackery that doesn't feel right to make everything play nice.